# How to hide loading image div from code behind

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

CSS:

```
    <style type="text/css">
    .modal
    {
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        background-color: black;
        z-index: 99;
        opacity: 0.8;
        filter: alpha(opacity=80);
        -moz-opacity: 0.8;
        min-height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
    }
    .loading
    {
        font-family: Arial;
        font-size: 10pt;
        border: 5px solid #67CFF5;
        width: 200px;
        height: 100px;
        display: none;
        position: fixed;
        background-color: White;
        z-index: 999;
    }
</style>
```

JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function ShowProgress() {
        // alert("aa");
        setTimeout(function () {
            var modal = $('<div />');
            modal.addClass("modal");
            $('body').append(modal);
            var loading = $(".loading");
            loading.show();
            var top = Math.max($(window).height() / 2 - loading[0].offsetHeight / 2, 0);
            var left = Math.max($(window).width() / 2 - loading[0].offsetWidth / 2, 0);
            loading.css({ top: top, left: left });
        }, 200);
    }
</script>
```

HTML:

```
 <div class="loading" align="center" id="loader">
                Loading. Please wait.
                <br />
                <img id="abc" src="../../Images/loader.gif" alt="" />
            </div>
<div>
  <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePaneltab" runat="server" UpdateMode="Always">
        <ContentTemplate>
<asp:Button ID="btnSearch" runat="server" Text="Run" CssClass="btn-in"   OnClick="btnSearch_Click"  OnClientClick="ShowProgress()" />
</ContentTemplate>
<Triggers>
            <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="btnSearch" />
        </Triggers>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

I am using above code to show loading image div on button click.But i am not able to hide it wherever i want to inside button click code.It automatically gets hidden after all the button click code is executed.I have exporttoexcel functionality and i want to hide it before my this functionality starts executing because once the exporting starts there is no control over the page and code.But the loading image continuously displays even when the exporting is done.
currently i am using

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "hwa", "document.getElementById('loader').style.visibility = 'hidden';", true);
```

to hide div.

I am not able to find out whats the issue.Is there something i am missing which i need to add in code.
Any suggestions ? any ideas?
Please helpme.I am stuck.

Answer (score 0):

You should put write a javascript function in a javascript file or in your aspx file.

```
function HideLoader() {
    $(".loading").hide();
    $(".modal").hide();
}
```

Then you should call this function in your startup script:

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "hwa", "HideLoader();", true);
```

Since the output of `RegisterStartupScript` is written into the page after the page is loaded, the inline script isn't executed.

***Edit:***

You should probably hide both the `.modal` `div` and the `.loading` `div`. I changed the javascript. You should put a breakpoint to HideLoader javascript function and see if it gets called. If it gets called and it doesn't hide the div, then you will have an easier time to solve the problem. Just correct the js function to hide the loading divs. If it doesn't get called, you should focus on RegisterStartupScript and see how you can make it call your function.

Comment: oops..sorry ..actualy its hidden.i posted a wrong line of code.its hidden only but still unable to hide it.

Comment: thanks for your solution.i tried your solution..but its not working